# configuration for launching gazebo world and model from a package

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, world, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package containing worlds that have several models defined in the models directory.

what configurations (e.g. in package.xml and CMakeList.txt) should I set in order to Gazebo and ROS work properly and detects my models?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373550/configuration-for-launching-gazebo-world-and-model-from-a-package/) by [Morteza70](https://answers.ros.org/users/31125/morteza70/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am also having the same problem. So this kind of question is already answered. [check here](https://answers.ros.org/question/195402/creating-custom-gazebo-world-files-from-sdfsdaes-for-use-with-roslaunch/?answer=357489#post-id-357489)
The directory of your world files should be something like this mentioned [here](https://github.com/harrisonwr/Cheatsheet/blob/master/ROS_Gazebo.md).

However, if your package have folder structure something like above, you could simply place these two lines of code,

```
<export>
<gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>
<gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path="${prefix}/models"/>
</export>
```

then you can use in sdf files

```
<mesh><uri>model://your_mesh.dae</uri></mesh>
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Shravista](https://answers.ros.org/users/60779/shravista/) with karma: 16 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0